# NUXTJS auth redirects to /login with query string if I'm login with Google strategy

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, nuxtjs

**After getting authenticated from google it redirects me to /login?state=....**

- I was implementing this from the documentation

My question is why I m not logged in?
There is no user data in this.$auth
And loggedIn property is also false
Is there any step todo further which I am missing out?

#### nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        responseType: 'code',
        codeChallengeMethod: '',
      },
   },
}
```

#### login.vue

```
    this.$auth.loginWith('google');
```

Comment: You have asked no question, only stated fact. What is your question?

Comment: Facing a similar issue but with Facebook. Any route with query string always redirects back to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix by replacing

```
responseType: 'token id_token',
```